# Cluster markers from different overlays with each other

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.markercluster

I use angular-leaflet with leaflet markercluster plugin (see http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/layers/overlays-markercluster-example for example).

Now I have three different overlays with 'clustermarker' type. At the moment markers of each overlay cluster only with markers from the same overlay. I would like all of them to cluster with each other. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in those extra Leaflet plugins:

- [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup)
- [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport)

But I am unsure about how to use them with Angular Leaflet Directive.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of those plugins.

Comment: `Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport` is a way. [Here](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport/issues/17#issuecomment-559613060) is (almost) locally working example.